# Is the the compound subject "I and my friend" grammatically correct as opposed to "My friend and I"?

Tags: pronouns, word-order, compound-subjects

Some people say it is outright wrong to use "I and my friend" or "I and my X". Their reasoning is it should be "My friend and I love the sun" is right because when separated "My friend loves the sun" and "I love the sun" both makes sense. But if I use "I and my friend" love the sun, they get split as "I love the sun" and "My friend love the sun". The latter is wrong. 
 Others say the sentence is right grammatically but not polite to use "I" before. 
So who is right?

Comment: I think it is a matter of respect. Saying "I and my friend" puts you first and the friend second.

Answer (score 2):

The only reason why "I and my friend" is discouraged is because it's considered discourteous to put yourself first.

When you say "My friend and I love the sun" the subject is plural, and then the plural form of "love" is required.  When you say "My friend loves the sun" you must use the 3rd person singular form of the verb -- "loves".

Comment: I know that this is commonly accepted as the reason, but If this were true, wouldn't we expect "my friend and me" to be much more common than "me and my friend"?  Surely, the rules of courtesy don't necessarily make sense, but it seems a little hard to believe that people think it's impolite to put yourself first as a subject, but it's OK to be the first object. I suspect that something else is involved.

Comment: @Juhasz That seems likely. Politeness is never the only reason for language features. In this case I would suspect that the strangeness of leaving _I_ out there at the beginning, stressed and uncontracted, an entire NP constituent by itself and part of a conjoined noun phrase, is what makes it feel weird. _I_ is normally contracted and rarely stressed.

Comment: @Juhasz "Me and my friend" is most often used incorrectly when the phrase is the subject of the verb. For example "Me and my friend went to the shops". In that case the correct form would be "My friend and I went to the shops". The prevalence of the "Me and my friend" form has, unfortunately, led to the opposite error becoming enormously common. A very large number of very expensively educated people say things like "My father threw a party for my sister and I". It's easy to find the correct form of the first person pronoun, just use it on its own without the other person involved.

Comment: @BoldBen - So you're telling me that ["Me and my shadow, strolling down the avenue"](https://youtu.be/N-L-PYnW8Uc?t=59) is wrong???

Comment: @BoldBen, you may be right that "me and my friend" is used more often as a subject, but how does that explain the "impolite" order? Is the thought that as long as you're making one mistake you might as well make two? Anyway, I share your frustration about that hypercorrection. I hear things like "Send that email to John and I" every day.

Comment: @HotLicks It's not really wrong because very few people say "It was I" any more but a real grammatical pedant would probably say that it was. However the song does _not_ say "Me and my shadow _strolled_ down the avenue" which would be grammatically incorrect. Also the shadow is not a person so does not get equal or superior biling to a human. It's the same as "I and my dog strolled down the avenue" or the caption of a photograph saying "Me and my dog strolling down the avenue"

Comment: @Juhasz I think that the "impolite" order convention is probably a middle class or upper class invention. The fact that oiks like me make two simultaneous mistakes just confuses the poor dears even more!